# Почему MongoDB и passportjs не работает при использовании camelCase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, passport

Использую passportjs и mongo в качестве бд. Делаю авторизацию, при регистрации в базу добавляю объект с именем и паролем. Если использую в качестве имени свойства username, то все работает как нужно. Но если меняю свойство на userName, то перестает работать, как будто в базе нет такого объекта. Изза чего может так происходить?

Comment: Может потому, что JavaScript чувствителен к регистру букв?

Comment: @Leonid Я учитываю это